# How to vary a specific variable during a SIMULINK simulation using Matlab programming

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am trying to vary a variable every 10 seconds while a simulation on simulink is running. I defined `(Kb+Ks)/N` inside some Gain blocks and I want to vary only Kb from its minimum to maximum value and back to its minimum value during simulation. I have tried using `set_param(model, parameter, value)` but it varies `(Kb+Ks)/N` instead of only `Kb`. I have also tried a 'for loop command,' however this runs the simulations one at a time. Please how do I solve this problem?

Comment: Instead of using K_b as a parameter, you could try using a signal generator block.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, you can't do what you want with a simple gain block. Replace `Kb` with a [Repeating Sequence](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/repeatingsequence.html) block, a [From Workspace](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/fromworkspace.html) block, or whatever source signal you want to use. Then add that signal to a constant block `Ks/N` and multiply the output of the add block to whatever signal was previously going through the gain block.

Comment: Thank you for the comments.